# Universal Windows Platform App SOAP request to internal server

Tags: c#, soap, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app, windows-10-mobile

I have a problem with the connection of my UWP App in Windows Store to an local network server out off the Store App.

My App is published in windows store and can be downloaded. 
There are SOAP-Requests to our local network Server (WSO2), but this app doesn't receive any response of our server.

But if i deploy this app directly to my Windows 10 Mobile device (Lumia 920) i get responses, when i'm in the network or with VPN (Citrix AnyConnect).

Do you know if the Windows Store blocks connections like this, or are any ports blocked?

Thanks for any tips :)

Comment: Do you have **Private Networks (Client & Server)** checked on the **Capabilities** tab of the appx manifest?

Comment: Since this is an internal server are you sure the user is on the right network to access the service.

Comment: @WiredPrairie Yeah, i have done this. Nothing changed ...
These Capabilities are checked internetClient, internetClientServer, privateNetworkClientServer

Comment: @KenTucker if i load the app out of the store with my mobile phone, i don't get access over WLAN or with VPN. It seems to be a problem with the proxy settings or the port, our WSO2 Server is called